# Storing JS Array in HTML Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to figure out how to use jQuery to store an array inside of an HTML element for later use.

When I access my element later on and print out the attribute's value of the element I get:

`[object Object]`

How do I parse this back into an array so I can access it?

In one of my files I have this:

```
$("#logInName").attr("assessments", assessments);
```

Then inside of one of my iFrames:

```
function getAssessments() {
    var assess = $("#logInName", window.parent.document).attr("assessments");
    console.log(assess.toArray());
}
```

Once again, the output is: `[object Object]`

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Here is what the array looks like before it's inserted into the element:

[image]

Comment: try `console.log(JSON.stringify(assess.toArray()));`

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` is what I got.

Comment: as a side note, storing data in HTML elements is a very bad idea in general..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSON (a.k.a. *JavaScriptObjectNotation*) to convert between plain objects and strings:

```
$("#logInName").attr("data-assessments", JSON.stringify(assessments));
```

and then retrieve it as:

```
var assessments = JSON.parse($("#logInName").attr("data-assessments"));
```

(it will also work with `"assessments"`, but including the `data-` prefix is convention to ensure forward-compatibility in future HTML versions)

Comment: Np. You can also use `$().data()` like [Danny's answer suggests](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24889377/2685386) but it has a couple of gotchas in it that are surprisingly poorly documented (esp. for such a common jQuery function) and can lead to really weird corner cases. This native JSON approach is [much more straightforward](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

Answer (score 0):

Convert your object's output to a valid JSON format using JSON.stringify.

Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(assess.toArray()));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
$("#logInName").data('assessments',assessments);
```

then retrieve

```
$("#logInName").data('assessments');
```

Comment: This isn't going to work if the data is set from one frame and read from another.